# How to define a function from a relation?? injectivity and surjectivity of a function?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

[My question (Function)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INZOZ.jpg)
I need to define functions with the same domain and codomain that describe the food choices of family members for each day of the week.

food list - { eggs, veg, cereal, croissants }
Member of the family - { Father, Mother, Daughter, Son }

I've constructed the relation but couldn't describe it as a function. please see the image for more detail

Comment: Calm down now, it's only math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function is a relation between two sets, the domain and the range, so the input and output need not be numbers. For example, with $f$ as your Monday function, we have f(father) = eggs, f(mother) = veg, f(daughter) = cereal, f(son) = veg. Here, $f$ is not injective as f(mother) = f(son), and $f$ is not surjective either, as croissant does not correspond to any element in the domain. Now with $g$ as your Tuesday function, we have g(father) = eggs, g(mother) = croissant, g(daughter) = cereal, g(son) = veg. Here, $g$ is both injective and surjective.

Comment: Thanks a lot. you are a legend!

Comment: You're welcome!